Bridge edge loops of two nested cylinders
I'm trying to connect two nested cylinders (with equal number of edges) but "Bridge edge loops" is not working for this.


I tryed to alter parameters of this function but uselessly. Maybe you know what is the fastest way to do it?

If you enable Face Orientation in the Overlays, I'm pretty sure it looks something like this:

The outer ring has its face normals pointing outwards (blue) and the faces of the inner ring are pointing in the same direction.
However if you want to create a ring with the top and bottom closed, the faces of the inner ring would have to point with their faces to the center of the ring to create manifold geometry.
So what you have to do is select all the inner faces, then hit Alt+N > Normals > Flip to invert the orientation and now the red side is pointing towards the outer ring:

If you now use the Bridge Edge Loops tool, it should work as expected:


I'm trying to repeat it but the inversion only affects one active face. What am I doing wrong?

@White_Scorpion Well, how are you exactly doing it? You have to select all the faces you want to flip, then press Alt+N and choose Flip from the opening menu.

I select it with "Select loop" then trying to flip it as being said. Here's the screenshots:
https://imgur.com/a/Ur3qEtb

@White_Scorpion There is something wrong with your mesh... when you select all faces of the loop, the top and bottom edges should be selected too - but they are not, they are black. Do you have duplicate geometry there? Try selecting all with A, then M > Merge by Distance.

I made it by simply selecting faces manually. Loop selection seems to only affect edges. But I shoud have used "Select linked flat faces" instead.

@White_Scorpion You selected faces manually? Have you maybe left some out? But your screenshot says you are in Face Select mode. It is not possible to select only edges without faces in that mode. And to select a face loop, hold Alt and click on the vertical edge between two faces. You should learn the many different basic selection methods in Blender. Have you tried merging vertices? If you can't get it to work you might have to upload your file for inspection.

I mean that it finally works with manual selecting. I just used wrong auto-selection before. Thank you for your tips! I use Blender too rarely to properly learn it.
